# Is the SessionFactory connection string used when evaluating identity in First and Second level caches

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

We have a custom connection string provider that connects to different databases based on the current context.

Doing so uses the same SessionFactory for all databases.

Assuming we may have entities with the same identifiers (i.e. primary key) in different databases, is this taken into account when an item is retrieved from either the first or second level caches?

So if Entity-1 for Db-1 is in the second level cache and I request Entity-1 for Db-2 will NHibernate load the entity from cache (incorrect) or the Db-2 database (correct).

Comment: My understanding is that you should always only have 1 session factory per db?

Comment: Would the same apply per-schema?

Comment: I suppose this would depend on whether the schema is taken into account when resolving identity.

Comment: I doubt it. My understanding is that 2nd level cache is partitioned per session factory. We do the same thing except we use one session factory per database. Obviously this will not scale forever but it's a web application so the session factories live on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit more research (namely [here](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate)):

The database name/schema is not used by either the first or second level caches to retrieve entities.

Whilst the second level cache is tied to the session factory, the cache provider you use is not guaranteed to be partitioned (see [here](http://ayende.com/blog/1708/nhibernate-caching-the-secong-level-cache-space-is-shared)).

The solution to this (assuming the cache provider supports it) is to set the `RegionPrefix` for the cache to be unique per tenant.